# Sum all records after last no good

Tags: sql, ms-access, query-optimization, jet

I work in a manufacturing environment and we have an Access database set up for recording no good part.  The two tables that we are currently working on are Occurrences and Sort.  Occurrences records the problem detail and Sort records the number of parts sorted and good/no good.  I have a query that I am trying to optimize that sums the number of parts sorted since the last defect was found. Here is the current (very messy) query:

```
SELECT Sort.[OccurrenceID], Sum(Sort.Sorted) AS SumOfSorted
FROM Sort
WHERE 
    (((Sort.SortDate)>(select top 1 dupe.sortdate from Sort as dupe where (((dupe.[OccurrenceID])=(Sort.[OccurrenceID])) and (((dupe.repaired)<>0) or ((dupe.scrapped)<>0))) order by dupe.sortdate desc, dupe.sortshift desc, dupe.id desc)))
OR (
     ((Sort.SortDate)>=(select top 1 dupe.sortdate from Sort as dupe where (((dupe.[OccurrenceID])=(Sort.[OccurrenceID])) and (((dupe.repaired)<>0) or ((dupe.scrapped)<>0))) order by dupe.sortdate desc, dupe.sortshift desc, dupe.id desc))
 AND ((Sort.SortShift)>(select top 1 dupe.sortshift from Sort as dupe where (((dupe.[OccurrenceID])=(Sort.[OccurrenceID])) and (((dupe.repaired)<>0) or ((dupe.scrapped)<>0))) order by dupe.sortdate desc, dupe.sortshift desc, dupe.id desc)))
OR (
     ((Sort.SortDate)=(select top 1 dupe.sortdate from Sort as dupe where (((dupe.[OccurrenceID])=(Sort.[OccurrenceID])) and (((dupe.repaired)<>0) or ((dupe.scrapped)<>0))) order by dupe.sortdate desc, dupe.sortshift desc, dupe.id desc))
 AND ((Sort.SortShift)=(select top 1 dupe.sortshift from Sort as dupe where (((dupe.[OccurrenceID])=(Sort.[OccurrenceID])) and (((dupe.repaired)<>0) or ((dupe.scrapped)<>0))) order by dupe.sortdate desc, dupe.sortshift desc, dupe.id desc))
 AND ((Sort.ID)>(select top 1 dupe.id from Sort as dupe where (((dupe.[OccurrenceID])=(Sort.[OccurrenceID])) and (((dupe.repaired)<>0) or ((dupe.scrapped)<>0))) order by dupe.sortdate desc, dupe.sortshift desc, dupe.id desc)))
GROUP BY Sort.[OccurrenceID];
```

This works, but takes forever to run.  I was trying to refactor out the 'dupe' subquery into its own stacked query and ended up with the following query I called SortRejects:

```
SELECT Sort.[OccurrenceID], Sort.SortDate, Sort.SortShift, Sort.ID, Sort.Scrapped, Sort.Repaired
FROM Sort
WHERE (((Sort.Scrapped)<>0)) OR (((Sort.Repaired)<>0))
ORDER BY Sort.SortDate DESC , Sort.SortShift DESC , Sort.ID DESC;
```

And the new final query:

```
SELECT Sort.[OccurrenceID], Sum(Sort.Sorted) AS SumOfSorted
FROM Sort
WHERE 
   (((Sort.sortdate)>(select top 1 SortRejects.sortdate from SortRejects where ((SortRejects.[OccurrenceID])=(Sort.[OccurrenceID])))))
OR (
     ((Sort.sortdate)>=(select top 1 SortRejects.sortdate from SortRejects where ((SortRejects.[OccurrenceID])=(Sort.[OccurrenceID]))))
 AND ((Sort.sortshift)>(select top 1 SortRejects.sortshift from SortRejects where ((SortRejects.[OccurrenceID])=(Sort.[OccurrenceID])))))
OR (
     ((Sort.sortdate)=(select top 1 SortRejects.sortdate from SortRejects where ((SortRejects.[OccurrenceID])=(Sort.[OccurrenceID]))))
 AND ((Sort.sortshift)=(select top 1 SortRejects.sortshift from SortRejects where ((SortRejects.[OccurrenceID])=(Sort.[OccurrenceID]))))
 AND ((Sort.ID)>(select top 1 SortRejects.id from SortRejects where ((SortRejects.[OccurrenceID])=(Sort.[OccurrenceID])))))
GROUP BY Sort.[OccurrenceID];
```

The result is much faster but does not return the same results.  Am I missing something or do stacked queries not work the same as sub queries in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... I'm not too up on Access syntax and use, so this may not be completely applicable.

It's possible that a stacked query is generating a temp table, which is *not* sorted.  Tables in SQL (not so sure about Access) have *no inherent order*.  It's possible, therefore, that when it goes to reference the stacked query rows, the access plan generated changes based on the columns referenced, as it attempts to optimize the path taken.

In any case, I'm not completely comfortable with either of those queries, something's just setting me off.  It's probably the constant re-use of `SELECT TOP 1` - normally I'd prefer to use a couple of CTEs to achieve the effect, but I don't think they're available in Access.  So here's some changes:

First off, you may want to change using `SortDate`, `SortShift` and `Sort.Id` to using just a plain timestamp (you're trying to find everything since occurence of a particular problem, right?).

Also, you're caring too much about the values of the 'previous' rows, when what you should be caring about are the values of the *current* (desired) rows (I fall into this occasionally, too).  You don't care about the 'top' row per se - our results need to be greater than **all** rows with defects.

So, if `Sort.id` is constantly increasing, and values are **NOT** reused you should just be able to use *that* single value, something like this (may be in Access syntax):

```
SELECT a.[OccurrenceId], SUM(a.sorted) as totalSorted
FROM Sort as a
LEFT JOIN Sort as b
ON b.[OccurrenceId] = a.[OccurrenceId]
AND (b.scrapped > 0  -- This is a count, right?
     OR b.repaired > 0)  -- see above
AND b.id > a.id
WHERE b.id IS NULL
GROUP BY a.[OccurrenceId]
```

Which basically gets all rows where there are no 'greater' rows (`Sort.id`) with `scrapped` or `repaired` not positive, for a given occurrence.  Please note that the way your query is written, if the 'greatest' row has some scrapped or repaired, it will return that row, with no indication that it's for a 'failed' run.

If `Sort.id` is reused (it may be per-shift, given it's use), it gets more complicated:

```
SELECT a.OccurrenceId, SUM(a.sorted) as totalSorted
FROM Sort as a
LEFT JOIN Sort as b
ON b.[OccurrenceId] = a.[OccurrenceId]
AND (b.scrapped > 0
     OR b.repaired > 0)
AND (b.sortDate > a.sortDate
     OR (b.sortDate = a.sortDate
         AND b.sortShift > a.sortShift)
     OR (b.sortDate = a.sortDate
         AND b.sortShift = a.sortShift
         AND b.id > a.id))
WHERE b.id IS NULL
GROUP BY a.[OccurrenceId]
```

I'm not guaranteeing that either of these versions will be faster, although they probably will be.  They are, however, much less 'skewed'.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use only `Sort.id`.  It is constantly increasing, however I cannot guarantee that everything is entered into the database in the correct order.  Also, I don't think Access likes the multiple conditions on the `ON` clause.  It complains about 'Join expression no supported'.

Comment: You may have to wrap the entire set of conditions in a set of parenthesis, I'm not sure.  I've never used Access, so I consider myself somewhat fortunate.

Answer (score 0):

It's highly possible that your original query is slow because of the use of sub-SELECT queries in the WHERE clause that may be executed for each record in your `Sort` table.

If I where you, I would use VBA to reduce each `SELECT TOP 1` to the single value they are checking, and then re-inject that into the main query.

```
Public Function GetMessyQuerySQL() As String

    ' First, extract our where-clause data SortDate, SortShift, and ID'
    Dim sql As String
    sql = sql & "SELECT TOP 1 sortdate, sortshift, id "
    sql = sql & "FROM   Sort "
    sql = sql & "WHERE  (OccurrenceID = OccurrenceID) "
    sql = sql & "        AND (Sort.repaired <> 0) "
    sql = sql & "              OR (Sort.scrapped<>0) "
    sql = sql & "ORDER  BY sortdate DESC, "
    sql = sql & "          sortshift DESC, "
    sql = sql & "          id DESC;"

    Dim SortDate as Variant, SortShift As Variant, ID as Variant

    ' We assume there is always a valid data return by that query! '
    Set rs = CurrentDb().OpenRecordset(sql, dbOpenForwardOnly)
    ' Convert dates to litteral dates in the format #29/03/2012# '
    SortDate = Format(rs(0), "\#mm\/dd\/yyyy\#") 
    SortShift = Format(rs(1), "\#mm\/dd\/yyyy\#") 
    SortID = rs(2)
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing

    ' Now, modify the main query with our data from the first '
    sql = vbNullString
    sql = sql & "SELECT OccurrenceID, "
    sql = sql & "       SUM(Sorted) AS SumOfSorted "
    sql = sql & "FROM   Sort "
    sql = sql & "WHERE  (SortDate > %SortDate) "
    sql = sql & "        OR ((SortDate >= %SortDate) "
    sql = sql & "            AND (SortShift > %SortShift)) "
    sql = sql & "        OR ((SortDate = %SortDate) "
    sql = sql & "            AND (SortShift = %SortShift) "
    sql = sql & "            AND (ID > %SortID)) "
    sql = sql & "GROUP  BY OccurrenceID;  "

    ' Replace the %xxx% by their proper values '
    sql = Replace(sql, "%SortDate", SortDate)
    sql = Replace(sql, "%SortShift", SortShift)
    sql = Replace(sql, "%SortID", SortID)

    ' Just return the constructed SQL '
    GetMessyQuerySQL = SQL
End Sub
```

So calling this function would get you SQL code like that:

```
SELECT OccurrenceID,
       SUM(Sorted) AS SumOfSorted
FROM   Sort
WHERE  (SortDate > #17/02/2012#)
        OR ((SortDate >= #17/02/2012#)
             AND (SortShift > #29/03/2012#))
        OR ((SortDate = #17/02/2012#)
             AND (SortShift = #29/03/2012#)
             AND (ID > 25))
GROUP  BY OccurrenceID;
```

Anyway that's just the basic principle, you can take it further and if your query is bound to a datasheet form for instance, you can do something like that in the Open event of the form:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
     Me.RecordSource = GetMessySQL()
End Sub
```

Comment: The problem I see with this is that it would use the same hard coded dates for every OccurrenceID.  I need to find the most recent entry in the Sort table that has either scrapped or repaired parts for each OccurrenceID.  Then I need to sum the number of parts sorted after the last defect was found for each OccurrenceID.

Comment: Oops, in my desire/haste to simplify things I missed that the subqueries were related to the main one. Guess I'll have to think of another solution...